# Trouble using Array.Reverse

Tags: c#

I am writing code to check for symmetry within a string. I convert to a Char array and then I would like to use the Array.Reverse method. I keep getting a cannot convert type void to Char[]. Any insight would be greatly appreciated my code is as follows.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        checkPalindrome("aabaa");
    }
   public static bool checkPalindrome(string inputString)
    { 
        char[] charArray = inputString.ToCharArray();
        char[] reverseArray = Array.Reverse(charArray);
        Array.Reverse(charArray);

    //Console.Write(charArray);
    //Console.Write(reverseArray);

    if (charArray = Array.Reverse(charArray))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: @huck_cussler `Array.Reverse` returns `void`, so neither the assignment nor the comparison will work.

Comment: @Amy Correct.  I will edit my comment to note that it is not relevant to OP's actual question.  Thanks.

Comment: `Array.Reverse` is an in place reverse, meaning it mutates the array.

Comment: @huck_cussler Even it if did return an array comparing them would be a reference equality check, not a check that each item in both arrays is equal.

Comment: @juharr Good point, thanks.  Sadly my five minutes for edits to my comment have expired now. =/

Comment: @huck_cussler But Delete never expires ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
char[] reverseArray = Array.Reverse(charArray);
```

Array.Reverse changes the contents of the array that you pass it. It doesn't return any value.

You can use LINQ to do something like this instead:

```
char[] reverseArray = charArray.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Then, when you're checking for equality, you need to do more than the default object-equals type of equality check:

```
if (charArray.SequenceEqual(reverseArray))
```

Also, `.ToArray()` is only necessary if you need an array, and you don't need one for `SequenceEqual()`. And the `if(something) {return true;} else {return false;}` pattern can be simplified to `return something;`

So the entire method can actually be written in a single line:

```
public static bool checkPalindrome(string inputString)
{ 
    return inputString.Reverse().SequenceEqual(inputString);
}
```

Comment: I truly appreciate your solution to my entire algorithim I will use your code in my final product. I am still confused as to why Array.Reverse(genericArray) cannot be applied to a simple if statement I still encounter the same char [] cannot be compared to void.

Comment: @AndrewMattick: An `if` statement has to take a boolean expression, and your boolean expression is a "binary expression" (meaning it has two parts) around the `==` operator. The left-hand side is a `char[]`, but the right-hand side is a call to a method that doesn't return anything (i.e. it's a "void" method). Calling `Array.Reverse` causes a side-effect on the parameter you give it, but since no value is returned, the method call can't be used in a context that needs to have some kind of value.

Answer (score 0):

A better way - no array cloning/array extraction:

```
    static bool checkPalindrome(string inputString)
    {
        var length = inputString.Length;
        var half = length / 2 + 1;
        return length <= 1 || inputString.Take(half).SequenceEqual(inputString.Reverse().Take(half));
    }
```

Comment: why do you call the extension method in such a weird way

Comment: To kinda emphasize the symmetry or the compared objects, but you're right - I changed it now. And optimized a little to check only the half.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way to determine symetry in a `string`.

```
public bool IsSymetric(string str)
{
    if(str == null) return true; // or false or throw an exception

    for(int i = 0; i < str.Length/2; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] != str[str.Length - 1 - i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```